# JQuery Accordian Width Style Issue

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to add some padding or space in between each of the Anchor Tag Questions for an Accordian.

Can someone guide me on what to change in the CSS?

Im trying to apply the same width between each of the Toggle Questions in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/yXNmx

For the Accordian Questions that is in this example (without any Jitter Effect): 
http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/Jv8Ta

This isnt for an event handler, the Question Links should have some space between them when the Page loads, as in the Toggle example above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.question
{
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

This pushes the next element down by `50px`, which adds some space in between questions.

Comment: That causes Jitter.  What I need is the initial space in between each of the Questions.

Comment: You'd then need to wrap the questions within another `<div>` tag, and apply `min-height: 100px;` to that tag. CSS isn't made to do dynamic things like that (easily).

Comment: It's not as good-looking, but it's much more readable and simpler http://jsfiddle.net/cv4v4/1/.

Comment: I see that one is for the Toggle.  Have you tried to alter my fiddle for the Accordian?

Comment: Like this http://jsfiddle.net/WNLjD/? I'm not sure what your exact question is. Could you be a bit more specific?

Comment: That example has Jitter also, notice when you click on any of the questions, the bottom jerks?  Thats the problem Im having when Im trying to add padding or a margin for this to give it some space between the question.  I will re-phrase the Problem above.

Comment: What browser are you using? I get no jitter whatsoever on any of these.

Comment: The Browser is IE8. I tried to add Padding as well to the Question wrapper Factterm, and this caused Jitter for me. Once the padding is removed, the jitter dissapears.

Comment: That's why. Switch to a standards-compliant web browser. I can rip IE to pieces with bits of flesh and blood spraying everywhere, but that's mean to do. Seriously, just download a *real* web-browser (like Chrome).

Comment: LOL Yes I have FireFox as well! The solution I gave isnt without its faults.  There is space between the Questions, however, this extra space expands the Handler's Background Color the grey when clicked.

Comment: Hmm, what do you mean? If you change `padding-bottom` to `padding`, you will get more uniform padding around the element.

Comment: @Blender Its the grey background color for the hyperlink which is activated when clicked. If you compare this example which is what I want http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/yXNmx this has the lighter blue color associated with the #faqColumn Class that is in between the grey background color(need to open both questions to see this) On the other hand, the Accordian just vertically stretches the grey background color to whatever height the padding-bottom of the .factterm Class. If the padding-bottom is 20px then the grey color would be very thick http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/Jv8Ta/

Comment: @Blender I think you nailed it!

Answer (score 0):

The padding-bottom for the Question Wrapper Factterm provides the space between Questions:
http://jsfiddle.net/NinjaSk8ter/Jv8Ta/
But this also causes the Anchor Tag Handler's Background grey color to expand its height accordingly:

```
.active {background:#a9a9a9}
```

, the grey when clicked, to expand its height accordingly.

```
.factterm {
/*margin-top: 2px;*/
/* padding: 2px 5px 0;*/
/*width: 525px;*/
padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I figured out why the jerky motion was happening. Check the CSS here (it's animated, and tiny): http://jsfiddle.net/cv4v4/8/.